# asp.net MVC3 ActionResult multiple models and a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

What I am trying to do using asp.net MVC3:

-User selects a **Category** from a list of Categories.

-The SubCategories page then displays a list of images found to represent that Parent Category as well as the list of **SubCategories**.

I run into the need for **multiple models** because the "**Category Images**" are associated with Category and not the "**SubCategory model**".  Yes I realize this seems like it has been asked many times before but the syntax is still foreign to a noob like me.  What goes where?

I got the Category -> Html.Actionlink to the controller to return a list of SubCategories part... but even if I did some left join to get category and list of images as well, how would I get those into the same view as the list of subcategories?

**Update**
Found this posting:

http://francorobles.wordpress.com/2011/05/03/returning-multiple-models-in-1-view-in-asp-net-mvc3/

**Question:**  Is that a valid approach?  My intellisense suggests no.

Comment: Based on your comments to marcind's answer, it is not possible to answer your question in a satisfactory manner.  You must first invest some time to learn the basics of MVC.  Go to http://www.asp.net/mvc and work through the tutorials.

Comment: @counsellorben you're right I do need to look into it more but I am totally stuck on this multi-model to view.  Specifically if I pass in a CategoryID to obtain both the subcategories and images.  If you know of any tutorials of such, thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases like this you need "view models", i.e. view-specific models that have all the data your view needs.

Comment: I simply don't know where I need to place this view model or what it is suppose to look like.  Noob here in a dark room...if someone said, "turn on the lights" I wouldn't know what the switch looks like or where it is...even if I "googled-it".  ;)

Comment: It's impossible to answer your question if you say you know nothing about MVC. To solve your problem we'd have to teach you all the MVC basics first. Not really the purpose of a Q&A site like StackOverflow.